# Show count of companies by number of products by using output of another chart

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI I have a table with company names and products, and a bar chart with the number of products for each company.  Now I want to create a bar chart which shows the count of companies by the number of products they have and need help creating a measure.

[image]

Comment: I think you want to "show the count of companies by number of product" instead of "show the count of companies by number of companies"

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a similar question, I found this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/cex6jh/grouping_by_a_calculated_count_field/) post that helped me create the chart I was looking for.  Here are the steps I took.

Create a new measure with this formula `ProductCount = count(purchases[Company])`

Then switch into the Data tab and create a new table using this formula: `NewTable = SUMMARIZE(ProductCount, purchases[Company],"ProductCount", count(purchases[Company])`

Go back to the Dashboard tab and drop in a new bar chart.  Then from the new data table grab the Company Count column (aka summed column) for the Axis and the Company Name column for the value.